# nvcc compiler not found on $PATH

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, theano, nvcc

I am getting the following error with theano:

> ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check
>   your nvcc installation and try again.

I've tried every solution given by previous questions. Running `nvcc -V` returns the following:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

And `which nvcc` returns the following:

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin//nvcc
```

I've also confirmed I have an nvcc file in `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin`.

I've ran the following commands to ensure nvcc can be found:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec bash
```

I've confirmed the nvcc location is definitely in $PATH as running `echo $PATH` returns the following:

```
/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin/:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin
```

Also if I open a python console and run `import os; print(os.environ["PATH"])` I get the following (same thing):

```
/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin/:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/bin:/home/paperspace/anaconda3/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/home/paperspace/src/torch/install/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin
```

My .theanorc file in /home/paperspace is as follows:

```
[global]
device = cuda
floatX = float32
[cuda] 
root = /usr/local/cuda-9.1
```